# snakemake - do not delete output of failed rules

Tags: snakemake

I have a snakemake workflow containing a rule that runs another "inner" snakemake workflow.
Sometimes a certain rule of the inner workflow fails, which means the inner workflow fails. As a result, all files listed under the `output` of the inner workflow are deleted by the outer workflow, even if the rules of the inner workflow that created them completed successfully.
Is there a way to prevent snakemake from deleting the outputs of failed rules? Or maybe you can suggest another workaround?
A few notes:

- The outputs of the inner workflow must be listed, b/c they are used as input for other rules in the outer workflow.
- I tried setting the outputs of the inner workflow as `protected`, but this didn't help.
- I've also tried adding `exit 0` to the end of the call to the inner workflow to make snakemake think it completed successfully,

like this:

```
rule run_inner:
    input:
        inputs...
    output:
        outputs...
    shell:
        """
        snakemake -s inner.snakefile
        exit 0
        """
```

but outputs are still deleted.
Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be to have `run_inner` produce a dummy output file that flags the completion of the rule. Rules following `run_inner` will take in input the dummy file. E.g:

```
rule run_inner:
    ...
    output:
        # or just 'run_inner.done' if wildcards are not involved
        touch('{sample}.run_inner.done'), 
    shell:
        'snakemake -s inner.snakefile'

run next:
    input:
        '{sample}.run_inner.done',
    params:
        real_input= '{sample}.data.txt', # This is what run_inner actually produces
    shell:
        'do stuff {params.real_input}'
```

If `snakemake -s inner.snakefile` fails, the dummy output will be deleted but `snakemake -s inner.snakefile` will restart from where it left.

Another opition could be to integrate the rules in `inner.snakefile` into your outer pipeline using e.g. the [include](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html) statement. I feel this option is preferable but, of course, it would be more complicated to implement.

Comment: Thanks! `include` was exactly what I needed and is actually pretty straightforward to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`--keep-incomplete`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#all-options) option to `snakemake`, either on the command line or via a [profile](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles). This will prevent removal of incomplete output files by failed jobs.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use `run` instead of `shell`:

```py
rule run_inner:
    input:
        inputs...
    output:
        outputs...
    run:
        shell("""snakemake -s inner.snakefile""")
        # Add your code here to store the files before removing
```

Even if the script in the `shell` function call fails, the files still exist until the script in the `run` section finishes. You may copy the files in a safe place there.

**Update:** You need to handle exceptions to continue execution whenever the script returns error. The script below illustrates the idea: the `print` function from the `except:` block prints `True`, the other from `onerror` prints `False`

```py
rule run_inner:
    output:
        "output.txt"
    run:
        try:
            shell("""touch output.txt; exit 1""")
        except:
            print(os.path.exists("output.txt"))

onerror:
    print(os.path.exists("output.txt"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting direction, but how would I get the output files back to their expected path this way? I'll need them there in order for the workflow to resume.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. If the `shell` command fails, snakemake will delete the files listed in `output` and exit. It will not go on and execute the rest of the `run` directive.

Comment: @dariober, don't think, just test. That is not the `shell()` function that removes the outputs, but the cleanup procedure of the rule. This procedure is not called until the `run` script finishes.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I tested it I still don;t think the run script runs to the end. In the run directory I put `shell("touch {output}; exit 1"); os.rename(output[0], output[0] + '.done')`. `shell` creates the output and fails so `os.rename` is never executed and `output[0] + '.done'` is not created. Can you post a repoducible example?

Comment: @dariober, hm, my initial script was incorrect. After wrapping the `shell` into try/except that starts working.

Answer (score 0):

The program "fails" when throws back a non-zero return value. Therefore we need to only "fix" this issue to trick the inner shell thinking that all programs have successfully finished. The easiest way is to use `some error command || true`. Below is a minimal example:

```
rule test:
    output:
        "test.output",
    shell:
        """
        touch test.output
        # below cat will trigger error 
        cat file_not_exist || true
        """
```

You'll find that despite the error thrown by `cat`, `test.output` still survives.